# Moving in together, separate finances

Tags: cost-of-living

As lovebirding life-partners in a no common-law-marriage state, we are going to be moving in together after 5 years, with the apartment-dweller ($1000/mo rent) moving into the home-owner's house ($2000/mo mortgage).  Finances kept separate, house remains 100% in the owners name.  We're in our late 30s, fwiw.

To be clear, those parameters are a given. They've been decided. We will be cohabitating the house.  The owner will always be the sole-owner of the house regardless of developments. The current house will not be sold and a new home bought. Finances will be kept as separate as possible.

The cohabitation-contract question is here:
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24790/cohabiation-contract

We have a plan for how to meet expenses.  Our current idea is to split the savings.  The formula for the exact savings is not clear.  We're not worried about what the formula might be.  We're happy to approximate the savings.  We're taking the relief of rent ($1000/mo) as the savings.  We'll split that savings and go 50/50 on utilities.  Effectively the move-ee contributes $500/mo to the cost of home ownership (mortgage, taxes, maintenance, repairs, insurance, ... ) but doesn't gain an interest in the house, and pays more in utilities than before.

We're both happy with that plan. Why might the cost-sharing plan not be good idea? or might not be a fair? For example, is there some other major savings component that we're not thinking of?

We're just looking for insight. Regardless of the responses, we're almost certainly going with split-the-savings approach.

The odd thing is that despite the curb appeal of "split-the-savings", the principle wouldn't make sense in similar situations. For example. Suppose the mortgage was $3000, half of which is interest. And suppose the apartment rent was $600. Finally suppose the plan was to sell the house and move into the apartment.  In that case the savings would be $1500 interest component of the the mortgage. Splitting that savings would mean the ex-owner would be contributing $750 by paying the full rent plus giving the $150 to the other.

Because fairness is not sustained when the split-the-savings principle is generalized, it seems like a false principle, and that the amount of our current plan ($500) is arbitrary, not principled.  We're uncomfortable with that, and are looking for deeper insight than we've been able to gain on our own.

As alternatives to the split-the-savings principle, we considered other bases such as the market values of 1) renting-out the entire house, 2) renting as a house-share, 3) renting a single room in the house, as well as other types of bases, such as proportioning expenses based on the two incomes.

Comment: Consider that depending where you live, living together for a certain period of time (in some places 6 months or less, in some places a couple of years at least) may make you be deemed to be common-law married. This can impact what is considered each of your separate assets, and what is considered to be a communal asset which would be split on separation (if that ever happens). Look up these laws in your particular jurisdiction.

Comment: What's the plan for when the mortgage is paid off?

Comment: I'm on the fence whether to vote to close this question as primarily opinion based, but FWIW, your plan seems both reasonable and fair to me. And just FYI, even many married couples have some amount of separate finances too.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon is there anywhere you could actually accidentally get married like that? I checked [the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-law_marriage_in_the_United_States) and it seems those states that have common-law marriage all require explicit intent and (for most) "holding out" as married (i.e. actually claiming to be).

Comment: @Kevin Yes, in Canada this is possible. See Quebec, for example: https://www.educaloi.qc.ca/en/capsules/common-law-couples-making-life-together-without-being-married "Most laws use the following criteria to determine whether a common-law relationship exists:... two unmarried people who live together and represent themselves in public as a couple" [Although how that common law status impacts communal property will vary greatly depending on circumstances.]

Answer (score 5):

This is almost exactly the situation my partner & I are currently in. There are a few things we took into consideration.

- Who is responsible for house repairs/improvements?
- What is the plan after the mortgage is paid off?

  - Does the renter get any benefits if the house is sold off?
- Do you want a formal renter's contract? (We made one.)

  - What are the terms of that contract?
  - What is the length on the contract?
  - Does it auto-renew?
  - Imagine the worst-cases of terrible break-ups, job losses, etc.
- What sort of relationship do you each have with money? What about as a couple?
- Are there any non-financial downsides to the move? (e.g. longer commute)
- What are the ramifications of moving in together (e.g. common law)

> Why might this not be good idea?  Or might not be fair?

Given those considerations, your question is less one about finance and possibly more about legal arrangements and the norms of your relationship. Overall, we could not come up with financial or legal reasons *not* to do this.

That said, it's important to acknowledge that this arrangement has an inherent power dynamic that may affect your relationship. One person legally controls the entire living situation. The other is contributing to a large investment that they likely will not directly gain from, which could be considered unfair or cause eventual resentment.

Comment: Awesome response. It's one of the types of feedback we are looking for.

Comment: Great answer. One note on the "power dynamic": as I see it, while there is "something there to consider", there's essentially no change from the point of view of the ex-renter. True, they don't own (or get to own) the house and are paying ~$500 to live there, but that's pretty much exactly their previous situation when renting, except they were paying $1,000 to do so.

Comment: @TripeHound - Could you explain more? We can't make out what you are saying. Thanks

Comment: @LadandLass I'll try... MagO mentions "_an inherent power dynamic_" in that one person will own/control the house, while the other is "just" in effect a renter. While that could be a concern in the future (and it may well be good to have "vague plans" to re-examine the arrangements in maybe 5 years time), what I was trying to say is that at least in the immediate future, the potential "power imbalance" may not be too much of a concern. [_**cont**_]

Comment: [_**cont**_] Essentially, the renter has gone from renting one property to "renting" another (with their "lovebird") and – should the worst happen – could go back to renting their own house again. In other words, while being aware that there _may_ be a "power dynamic", and you may want to revisit arrangements in a few years time, I don't think it should be a reason for not going ahead with your current plans.

Comment: @TripeHound -  thanks for the clarification.  One thing no one has mentioned is the following perspective. Both are putting away $1500 per month. The non-owner is putting $500 of that into the house, and $1000 of that into a retirement account.  The owner is putting all $1500 into the house. Assuming separate finances continues until retirement, the owner will end up with the house free and clear, and the non-owner will end up with a sizable nest egg.

Comment: Another adjacent note for future readers...the rent you collect is probably taxable income, so don't forget to declare that if you're a strict law-abiding citizen.

Answer (score 3):

This is **NOT** a financial decision. I repeat this is not a financial decision. It is a beliefs and values decision. Therefore I will answer based on straight opinion, not math.

`Short answer:` this is a good idea in the short term, bad idea in the long term.

`Long Answer:` what is your long term plan? You guys seem to be tippy-toeing into a committed relationship, and using financial contortions to make it work.

Not only are there major *downsides*, the ***upsides*** are fraught with danger as well. Consider what happens if the house increases in value? How does the non-equity holding partner make out? Is it based on the whim of the equity partner, or is there some pro-rata formula at the ready?

If you plan to be soul-mates and not roommates, plan on selling your residence and taking on new home where the financial risk and reward are commingled based on means.

This is not a money question but a relationship one.

Answer (score 2):

Your plan seems fair - one  partner is saving $500 in rent with nothing in return (financially, at least) AND getting a bigger (presumably) home.  The other is saving $500 on the mortgage and keeping all of the equity. So you both are equally better off than you were before.

Whatever your final arrangement is, I would strongly suggest putting the terms in writing. God forbid your "lovebirding" will end, but when it does you both want to be treated fairly in the end. You don't need a formal contract or to hire an attorney (though it wouldn't hurt) - just something that either of you can use to prove the terms should it be necessary.

Don't think of is as "distrust" - think of it as formalizing the terms you both agree to now and protecting each other from rash, emotional decisions.

Comment: Thanks. Owner is also saving about 40% overall on utilities and the $500 is after-tax.

Comment: One conundrum that is hard to figure out is that 'spliting-the-savings' wouldn't seem fair if reversed. If the move was to the apartment, the analogous savings would be $2000 (mortgage). Splitting that would mean the owner would be paying the full rent.

Comment: @LadandLass but remember in that scenario you'd sell the house, pay off the mortgage, and keep the difference, plus would stop paying interest. You'd both split the $1,000 rent, so one would still be saving $500; the other would be saving ($2000 - 500 - interest portion of mortgage).

Comment: It is true that the current plan boils down to "splitting the rent", but we are thinking of the underlying principle as split-the-savings. That principle doesn't seem fair in the reverse scenario (moving into the apartment). The savings would be $2000.

Comment: From a cash-flow perspective, yes, but part of that is going to equity in the house, so your _real_ savings in only the interest part, which is probably _more_ then $1,000 but less that $2,000. So yes combined you save somewhere between $1,000 and $2,000 but you move from a house to an apartment.

Comment: @LadandLass If you were to reverse the situation, it wouldn't be analogous. A $2000 a month mortgage that grants you $1000 a month in equity is really only a $1000/month cost in the long run. Granted you also save on home repairs,  and avoid fluctuations in the home price (for better or worse), and give up ownership in exchange for answering to a landlord, etc. Your situation is much easier because your partner is still renting and you are still owning, so the only real difference is the rent cost. So it makes sense to simply split the savings.

Comment: Put another way, the reverse would be that you split the renn - she'd save $500, you'd save (interest - $500) but move from a house to an apartment.

Comment: Excellent point to split out equity and interest. I think that is a more accurate assessment. In this case the interest and the rent are both about the same, so the two situations work out to the same $500. But in other reasonable situations, the numbers could be skewed. For example, the owner is paying $1500 in interest on a $3000 mortgage and the rentee is paying $600 to the landlord.

Comment: In our situation the $500 seems substantial, reasonable, and fair to both of us.  Coincidentally, that amount is also the split-the-savings amount.  That principle has a lot of curb appeal. It makes the amount ($500) sound reasoned, not arbitrary.

Comment: But because the principle does not work in other reasonable situations (ex: $3000 mortgage, $600 rent), it's false to claim it as the basis in our situation. The $500 is really arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider the opportunity cost the person with the mortgage on the home may be subjecting themselves to in offering the rent-ee to pay half of what they **used to pay at their previous residence** - which likely has a substantially lower value than a $2000/mo mortgaged home - and split the utilities at the new residence, compared to the actual value of the mortgaged property that's being shared / split.

I think the most fair situation would be for the person whom owns the mortgaged property to work out what a fair amount of 'rent' would be for the property if they were to rent out half of it to someone, as well as consider the idea of having the rent-ee purchase half of the home from them via a mortgage / co-sign onto a refinance of the existing mortgage or something similar, and work out what that would cost and whether it suits the needs of the two.

In my mind, if the mortgaged property is worth $2,000 per month, and the person moving in will be using an equal share of it, let's just say each person is getting about half the value of the property (as opposed to having someone stay in just one room of the house at any given point in time), it would be reasonable for the person moving in to pay half the $2,000 mortgage, **as well as their portion of the utilities**. Now, it does also make sense not to subject someone you love to this, especially if it's not something they'd be able to afford; you'll be able to figure out what would be fair in this scenario, but to me it would come down to what value they were getting out of the home they were moving into, and less about the place they were leaving.

**If it doesn't make financial sense** to the person moving in to your mortgaged property, because it costs too much, consider if it would make more sense **for the two of you** if the person owning the mortgaged property sold, and moved to a less expensive property with the person who's currently renting. At that point, you could decide to co-own, or rent half to the current renter, but would likely benefit both partners as they'd have the ability to identify a space that suits both partners financial needs.

While this decision is not just about finances, the answer to what the best outcome may be will likely require you to identify and address the long term goals of both people in this situation, as objectively as possible, and identify a way to reach those goals together.

Doing this, you may even come up with a few new ideas to benefit the both of you while eventually reaching the goals you lay out for yourself, such as possibly paying off your existing property, finding new property and renting the existing one out to others to generate income, something else; I don't know and it doesn't really matter to me - What matters is what the two of you want out of the situation long-term, and what the two of you can come up with to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

All of this advice is given under the typical IANAL.

As many other answer state this really isn't a financial decision. You are both clearly going to be better off financially in the short team (both saving £500).

You are not married (I assume) therefore if things go sideways then it can quickly fall into a he said/she said situation where one party assumes one thing (eg. It's 100% my house no matter what) while the other party assumes another (if the value of the house increases I should get part of it).

You best bet is to set up a lodging contract. You can find simple versions for free on the internet. This however isn't the hard part.

The hard part is one partner getting the other partner to agree to this without seeming like *the bad guy* or *an untrustworthy SOB*. Allow me to step in:

This is for both of your benefit.  The house owner needs to protect their assets.  The rentee needs to protect their liability - the owner could argue the rentee agreed to pay 500/month indefinitely for a 0.1% share and upkeep.

There we go. Now I'm the bad guy. True to form though I do have one more thing to say:

*What if you knew all this, and just wanted someone else to step in and be the bad guy... who's the bad guy now?*

Comment: The owner doesn't want a contract. The rentee thinks a contract would be good idea.  It's a financial decision.

Comment: The rentee should stand their ground - convince the owner that it's what's best for their asset (the house). In fact there may be something specifically stated in the mortgage agreement about this type of thing (not specifically this, but situations in general). You're protecting yourself against the bank aswell if you have a contract.

Comment: Good point on the rentee protecting their liability.

Comment: The only was this *is a financial decision* is if your asking about how to split the money. Eg. Should we get some savings going to buy a new car. Otherwise you're not asking about finance you're asking about fairness which, unlike finances, is subjective. The worst part of this being subjective is that it's not just subjective to the person (owner/renter) but also to time (now/future). What seems fair to you today may not seem fair tomorrow.

Comment: What you are saying, correct me if I am wrong, is that there are two issues. 1) how to meet expenses and 2) protection in case of nastiness.  And your opinion is that #2 is huge, several orders of magnitude greater than #1.

Comment: I didn't realise your questions was how to meet expenses. You're going to be each gaining $500/month extra - if you are managing now you will be fine after.

Comment: That is a more narrow view of 'how to meet expenses' than I intended.